# How to obtain entity attributes in the WebSocketSession interface of org.springframework.websocket5.3.26 : 'User'

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5vC7.png)

I try to get map in：session.getAttributes() , but this.size is zero i dont see any method can do this in websocketsession
code:

```
    @Override
    public void handleOpen(WebSocketSession session) {
        sessions.add(session);
        int count = connectionCount.incrementAndGet();
        log.info("a new connection opened，current online count：{}", count);
    }
```